# Potential on a Charged Sheet

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy

I know the field difference across a charged sheet-but what's the potential on a charged sheet? Is it just asymptotic?
If we had a thin cylindrical sheet would it be the same? Zero field inside the cylinder, and jump to infinity on the sheet, and q/r outside?

Answer (score 1):

If you take $U_{\infty}=0$ then $U_{sheet}=\infty$ (for infinite sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that potential is not an absolute so the actual value of the potential at a point has no meaning. For the cylinderical case $\vec{E} = \frac{\lambda}{2\pi \epsilon_0 r} \hat{r}$ outside the cylinder and zero inside.  and $V = \frac{-\lambda}{2\pi \epsilon_0}\ln r$ outside and $V=constant$ inside.